# Method of Proof

Tags: proof-writing

Consider a theorem of the form: (Something) iff $\exists$ a continuous function $f: X \rightarrow Y$ s.t. (something about the function).

I'm unsure how one would go about proving the $(\rightarrow)$ direction.

So we suppose that (Something) is true, and we WTS that there exists a continuous ...

But in terms of showing the part on the right, do we let $f$ be a continuous function and then show the s.t. portion? Or do we let $f$ be a function s.t. (something about the function) and then show that $f$ is continuous? Or am I only allowed to let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ and then have to show $f$ is continuous **and** the s.t. (something about the function) follows as well?

Thanks!

Comment: To convert the theorem into "if p, then q", you need to make sure what you want to implicate: continuity of f or the s.t. part of a continuous function.  
If you want to prove the existence of continuous function, you can take s.t. portion into if clause, i.e., hypothesis part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do we let $f$ be a continuous function and then show the s.t. portion?

No, because then you would show that every continuous function has that portion, which is not always true.

> Or do we let $f$ be a function s.t. (something about the function) and then show that $f$ is continuous?

No, because then you would show that every function with that portion is continuous, which is also not always true.

> Or am I only allowed to let $f:X\to Y$ and then have to show $f$ is continuous and the s.t. (something about the function) follows as well?

No, because then you would prove that **every** function is continuous and has that portion. Which is not true.

---

What you need to do: assume (something), then construct a continuous function with that portion. So you really need to **make** a continuous function yourself and prove that it has that portion (all based on the assumption of something).